# How do I redirect to the same page in Flask, generated by a GET request, following a POST request?

Tags: python, flask, post, redirect, get

I am creating a webapp with Python/Flask. I am using blueprints.

Say I search for a book and end up at the URL `/search?book=somebook&author=someauthor` via a GET request. On that page I have buttons for each result which will save that result to the user's saved books. This would be a `POST` request. However, I want to return the user to the same search page with the same URL params.

So the flow is:

1. User submits a search and ends up on `/search?book=somebook&author=someauthor`
2. User clicks subscribe on one of the results. A `POST` saves the book to the user's saved books.
3. User ends up on `/search?book=somebook&author=someauthor` again and the search result page is repopulated.

I think, incorrectly, I want something like this:

```py
@search_bp.route('/search', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def search():
    if request.method == "POST":
        # save book to user's saved books
        # somehow end up back on the same page from here

    elif request.method == "GET":
        # use request.args to populate page with results

        return render_template("search.html", books=books)
```

In my mind I want to `return redirect(url_for("search_bp.search"))` but somehow get the `request.args` back into the URL. Is my only choice to hardcode the URL, i.e. concatenate a string `url = "/search?book=" + request.args.get("book") + "&author=" + request.args.get("author")` so that I can `return redirect(url)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass values/variables to `flask.url_for`, example:

```py
book = request.args.get('book')
author = request.args.get('author')
my_url = url_for('search_bp.search', book=book, author=author)
```

Additional values/parameters passed to `url_for` will be added to the URL as GET parameters, then you can do `return redirect(my_url)`.

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.url_for

Comment: Ah I'm a dolt. I thought that would pass them as template variables. I'll try it out tomorrow and approve your answer then.